# Difference between two white spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This may sound stupid question but i can't figure out why in a string

> This is some random text.

I can't find any spaces in this string

Then I thought may be i just copy the blank space between two words and compare with space guess what it gives false

```
console.log(' ' == ' ');
```

here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/svfq0rs2/)

couldn't figure out why this is happening

**UPDATE**

Is there any way to find any type of blank spaces in string weather that be any any character code?

Comment: [There are many different spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character)

Comment: thank you but how would i compare these spaces if need to get only the last word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the string is using the html entity `&nbsp;` which is a non-breaking space character, which is indeed different than the `' '` space character.

Comment: I thought this too but when i compared it with &nbsp; still giving false

Comment: well i think i need to compare it like this to work  `" "== String.fromCharCode(160)`